# How to visualize eigenspaces of a rotation matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, rotations

Think of a rotation along the z axis. There's one real eigenspace on the z axis of course but the other two are complex conjugates. My intuition says that they must be related to the x,y plane. Is this correct?